# how to recover java.lang.NullPointerException when reading database?

Tags: java, database

I'm new to java. I use net beans IDE and Trying to read data from MySQL database table, Database connected successfully, but error arises when reading data. Anyone can help please...

```
public void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection MyConn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,User,Password);
        if (MyConn != null) {
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to the database");
            String ss="Select * from user;";
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(ss);
            if (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(0));
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Database connection error");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace for the NullPointerException tells you the statement causing the problem. So figure out which variable at that statement is null and then fix the problem.  Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: What happens when you connect to the database manually (without java) and do the query "Select * from user;"?

Comment: Thank you @camickr identified the statement. I not used Myconn.createStatement() method. Now OK. Thank you.

Comment: @NomadMaker Normally query runs and return table data. the error was with stmt object. I didn't used createStatement() method. Thank you for responce.